# Feeding R data to html in R markdown, where the output is a Word document

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I would like to automatically create a table in R Markdown, where the table is created in `html`, but the data comes from `R`. Could anyone help me with how to do this?

R data:

```
dat <- structure(list(rn = c("W", "M"), `[      0,     25)` = c(5L, 
0L), `[     25,     50)` = c(0L, 0L), `[     25,    100)` = c(38L, 
3L), `[     50,    100)` = c(0L, 0L), `[    100,    250)` = c(43L, 
5L), `[    100,    500)` = c(0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

   rn [      0,     25) [     25,     50) [     25,    100) [     50,    100) [    100,    250) [    100,    500)
1:  W                 5                 0                38                 0                43                 0
2:  M                 0                 0                 3                 0                 5                 0
```

Html code:

```
  <html>   
       <table border="1">
       <tr>
           <td width="150">Lower threshold</td>
           <td width="50">0</td>           
           <td width="50">25</td>
           <td width="50">50</td>
           <td width="50">100</td>
           <td width="50">250</td>       
       <tr>
           <td width="150">Upper threshold</td>
           <td width="50">25</td>
           <td width="50">50</td>
           <td width="50">100</td>
           <td width="50">250</td>
           <td width="50">500</td>     
       <tr>
           <td width="150">Category W</td>
           <td width="100" colspan="1">5</td>
           <td width="100" colspan="2">38</td>
           <td width="100" colspan="2">5</td>
       </tr>   
       <tr>
           <td width="150">Category M</td>
           <td width="100" colspan="1">0</td>
           <td width="100" colspan="2">3</td>
           <td width="100" colspan="2">5</td>
       </tr>
```

[image]

## EDIT: Formatting

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to create your HTML table from scratch which makes heavy use of `htmltools` and `purrr` may look like so. To make this work you have to do some data wrangling to put your data and the info needed to create your data in a tidy data format:

````
---
title: "HTML Table"
date: '2022-04-19'
output: html_document
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
dat <- structure(list(
  row = structure(c(
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L
  ), .Label = c(
    "Lower threshold",
    "Upper threshold", "Category W", "Category M"
  ), class = "factor"),
  value = c(
    0, 25, 50, 100, 250, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500, 5,
    38, 5, 0, 3, 5
  ), width = c(
    50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50,
    50, 50, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100
  ), colspan = c(
    NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2
  )
), row.names = c(
  NA,
  -16L
), class = "data.frame")
```

```{r}
head(dat)
```

```{r echo=FALSE}
make_html_table_row <- function(row, label) {
  htmltools::tagList(
    htmltools::tags$td(label, width = "150"),
    purrr::pmap(row, function(row, value, width, colspan) {
      htmltools::tags$td(value, width = width, colspan = if (!is.na(colspan)) colspan)
    })
  ) |>
    htmltools::tags$tr()
}

make_html_table <- function(x) {
  x_split <- split(x, x$row)
  purrr::imap(x_split, make_html_table_row) |>
    htmltools::tagList() |>
    htmltools::tags$table(border = "1") |>
    htmltools::tags$html()
}
```

```{r results='asis'}
make_html_table(dat)
```
````

[image]

**DATA**

Code used to create the data.

```
dat <- list(
  data.frame(
    row = "Lower threshold",
    value = c(0, 25, 50, 100, 250),
    width = 50,
    colspan = NA
  ),
  data.frame(
    row = "Upper threshold",
    value = c(25, 50, 100, 250, 500),
    width = 50,
    colspan = NA
  ),
  data.frame(
    row = "Category W",
    value = c(5, 38, 5),
    width = 100,
    colspan = c(1, 2, 2)
  ),
  data.frame(
    row = "Category M",
    value = c(0, 3, 5),
    width = 100,
    colspan = c(1, 2, 2)
  )
) |>
  dplyr::bind_rows()

dat$row <- factor(dat$row, levels = c("Lower threshold", "Upper threshold", "Category W", "Category M"))
```

Comment: Hi Stefan, thanks again, your code works great. I was trying to add some basic formatting to the table (see EDIT). I tried to implement them in the `tags$table(border = "1")`  part, but without much success. Could you perhaps give me one example of how adding the formatting should work?

Comment: I made a new question for my comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71997074/html-formatting-in-rmarkdown