# Casting the difference between two vectors into a specified format

Tags: r, melt, dcast

I am trying to create code that automatically creates data in the format below (for more background on the `colspan` see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71966045/feeding-r-data-to-html-in-r-markdown-where-the-output-is-a-word-document)).

I need to do two things:

1. Calculate the "difference" or "distance" for lack of a better word between two vectors.
2. Somehow cast or transpose the data.

I have no idea where to start, so I was hoping someone could help me get started.

## Desired format

```
lower_threshold <- data.frame(row=c("Lower threshold"), freq = c(0, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500, 1000, 1500, 3000, "Infinity", "SUM"), width=50, colspan=1)

               row  freq width colspan
1  Lower threshold     0    50      1
2  Lower threshold    25    50      1
3  Lower threshold    50    50      1
4  Lower threshold   100    50      1
5  Lower threshold   250    50      1
6  Lower threshold   500    50      1
7  Lower threshold  1000    50      1
8  Lower threshold  1500    50      1
9  Lower threshold  3000    50      1
10 Lower threshold   SUM    50      1
```

## Data to be formatted

The data I have is as follows:

```
dat <- structure(list(Name = c("Name_a", 
"Name_b"), freq = list(bb = c(5, 4, 3, 2, 14), aa = c(1, 6, 0, 7)), columns_used = list(bb = c(0, 25, 100, 500, "Infinity", "SUM"), aa = c(0, 25, 3000, "Infinity", "SUM"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

## Calculating colspan/width

I want to calculate `colspan` and `width` (which is simply `50*colspan`) based on the difference between the `columns_used` column and the following vector:

```
total_colspan = c(0, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500, 1000, 1500, 3000, "Infinity", "SUM")
```

As an example, for `Name_a`, the first `colspan` would be `1` (and `width=50`), because the first threshold is `0-25` for both vectors. However `Name_a` skips the number `50`, so the next `colspan` should be `2` (and `width=100`).

## Desired output:

```
   row         row freq  width colspan
1  Name_a              5    50      1
2  Name_a              4   100      2
3  Name_a              3   100      2
4  Name_a              2   200      4
5  Name_a             14    50      1
6  Name_b              1    50      1
...
11 Name_b              7    50      1
```

Where the sum of `colspan` for each `Name_x` should be 10 in total and `row_freq` comes from the `freq` column in `dat`.

The idea is to use the desired output to create a `hmtl` table:

[image]

Comment: Why is `colspan` 4 for width = 200 in the desired output?

Comment: @Maël It is just `4x50=200`. So `50` per `colspan`.

Comment: Alright, and why is it 4? it's still unclear as to how width/colspan is computed.

Comment: I understand, I had a hard time explaining. It is 4 because it skips `1000, 1500 and 3000`, so it needs to get a colspan of 4 times as wide (it will reflect the range of `500-infinity`), so 4 columns, instead of `500-1000`, which would be one column.

Comment: Maybe the link I added at the top explains the purpose of the `colspan` a little bit better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can certainly be improved, but here's a rough way to do it:

```r
l <- lapply(dat$columns_used, \(y) sapply(y, \(x) which(total_colspan == x) - which(y == x)))

dat[1:2] %>% 
  unnest_longer(freq) %>% 
  mutate(colspan = unlist(lapply(l, \(x) diff(x) + 1)),
         width = colspan * 50)

# A tibble: 9 x 4
  Name    freq colspan width
  <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 Name_a     5       1    50
2 Name_a     4       2   100
3 Name_a     3       2   100
4 Name_a     2       4   200
5 Name_a    14       1    50
6 Name_b     1       1    50
7 Name_b     6       7   350
8 Name_b     0       1    50
9 Name_b     7       1    50
```

Note: `\(x)` is a shortcut for `function(x)`.

Comment: This is really great, thank you sooo much!

Comment: Hey Maël, I am trying to adapt this solution, but I am having a bit of difficulty figuring out how `l <- lapply(dat$columns_used, \(y) sapply(y, \(x) which(total_colspan == x) - which(y == x)))` works exactly. Any chance you could explain it to me a little bit?

Comment: IIRC, this gives you for each element (`x`) in the list `dat$column_used` (`y`) the difference between the position of the element x in the vector `total_colspan` and the position of the element x in the vector `dat$column_used`.