# HTML formatting in Rmarkdown

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71966045/feeding-r-data-to-html-in-r-markdown-where-the-output-is-a-word-document) from stefan to automatically create tables in R-markdown as below.
It works great but I would like to add some formatting to the code. I have tried to add some `html` code to the tags in the functions, but I am not getting the expected results. As an example of the formatting I would like to add the formatting below, taken from [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_intro):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>
```

The orginal solution is as follows:

````
---
title: "HTML Table"
date: '2022-04-19'
output: html_document
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
dat <- structure(list(
  row = structure(c(
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L
  ), .Label = c(
    "Lower threshold",
    "Upper threshold", "Category W", "Category M"
  ), class = "factor"),
  value = c(
    0, 25, 50, 100, 250, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500, 5,
    38, 5, 0, 3, 5
  ), width = c(
    50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50,
    50, 50, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100
  ), colspan = c(
    NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2
  )
), row.names = c(
  NA,
  -16L
), class = "data.frame")
```

```{r}
head(dat)
```

```{r echo=FALSE}
make_html_table_row <- function(row, label) {
  htmltools::tagList(
    htmltools::tags$td(label, width = "150"),
    purrr::pmap(row, function(row, value, width, colspan) {
      htmltools::tags$td(value, width = width, colspan = if (!is.na(colspan)) colspan)
    })
  ) |>
    htmltools::tags$tr()
}

make_html_table <- function(x) {
  x_split <- split(x, x$row)
  purrr::imap(x_split, make_html_table_row) |>
    htmltools::tagList() |>
    htmltools::tags$table(border = "1") |>
    htmltools::tags$html()
}
```

```{r results='asis'}
make_html_table(dat)
```
````

[image]

**DATA**

Code used to create the data.

```
dat <- list(
  data.frame(
    row = "Lower threshold",
    value = c(0, 25, 50, 100, 250),
    width = 50,
    colspan = NA
  ),
  data.frame(
    row = "Upper threshold",
    value = c(25, 50, 100, 250, 500),
    width = 50,
    colspan = NA
  ),
  data.frame(
    row = "Category W",
    value = c(5, 38, 5),
    width = 100,
    colspan = c(1, 2, 2)
  ),
  data.frame(
    row = "Category M",
    value = c(0, 3, 5),
    width = 100,
    colspan = c(1, 2, 2)
  )
) |>
  dplyr::bind_rows()

dat$row <- factor(dat$row, levels = c("Lower threshold", "Upper threshold", "Category W", "Category M"))
```

Could anyone show me where the tags should go, either in the function or in the data?

Comment: Your question asks about HTML tables, but in a comment to a good solution you then state that what you actually want is a word document?? Please edit the question to be specific as to what you are needing help with...

Comment: @dario The question was based on a misunderstanding between stefan and I. I asked for a Word-document solution in the previous question. I only figured out his solution was not suitable for Word after asking this second question. How about I simply remove the comment I made and leave the question as is?

Comment: I still don't understand: That would mean you got the answer to your question? In that case you should accept the answer... if not it would make sense to leave these comments in order not to confuse others who would want to help you...

Comment: No, but stefan got the answer to the question I actually asked (instead of the one I intended to asked. So it's not an answer to my question, but it is an answer to what I posted). So if I remove the comments a third person will no longer be confused..

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty approach to achieve your desired result would be to add the CSS directly to your markdown file:

````
---
title: "HTML Table"
date: '2022-04-19'
output: html_document
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
dat <- structure(list(
  row = structure(c(
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L
  ), .Label = c(
    "Lower threshold",
    "Upper threshold", "Category W", "Category M"
  ), class = "factor"),
  value = c(
    0, 25, 50, 100, 250, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500, 5,
    38, 5, 0, 3, 5
  ), width = c(
    50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50,
    50, 50, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100
  ), colspan = c(
    NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2
  )
), row.names = c(
  NA,
  -16L
), class = "data.frame")
```

```{r}
head(dat)
```

<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>

```{r echo=FALSE}
make_html_table_row <- function(row, label) {
  htmltools::tagList(
    htmltools::tags$td(label, width = "150"),
    purrr::pmap(row, function(row, value, width, colspan) {
      htmltools::tags$td(value, width = width, colspan = if (!is.na(colspan)) colspan)
    })
  ) |>
    htmltools::tags$tr()
}

make_html_table <- function(x) {
  x_split <- split(x, x$row)
  purrr::imap(x_split, make_html_table_row) |>
    htmltools::tagList() |>
    htmltools::tags$table() |>
    htmltools::tags$html()
}
```

```{r results='asis'}
make_html_table(dat)
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. But does this not only work if the output is also a `html` document? I actually have a Word document as output..

Comment: Nop. But in that case adding an HTML table doesn't work either. If your final format is Word than I would suggest to create your table via the `flextable` package.

Comment: I think we had some miscommunication in the previous question then:) I tried your suggestion to use `flextable`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71998959/using-add-header-row-from-flextable-to-create-columns-of-varying-widths, but it seems to be a bust as well. Is there no package that allows Rmarkdown to render `html`?

Comment: Hi Tom. The issue is not with rendering HTML. That works fine. And of course would it be great if we could simply do HTML and convert it to Word afterwards. Would be much easier than fiddling around with Office and OOXML. But TBMK there are no such options and the `flextable` (and `officedown`) package is IMHO the best option to create customized tables if you want to export to Word.